# OpenCV Individual Pixel Access

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV and have been going through various tutorials and books.  I've ran into an odd problem.  I have a 3 row, 3 column 3-channel matrix in OpenCV I named test.  I filled it with dummy data like so:

```
Mat test(3,3, CV_8UC3, Scalar(50,100,200));
```

When I print out the matrix I get:

```
[[[50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200]], 
  [[50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200]], 
  [[50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200], [50, 100, 200]]]
```

So far so good.

I want to access each individual RGB values for row 1, column 1.  I read in the documentation and other answers on StackOverFlow to do the following for individual pixel access:
    test.at(1,1)[0];

When I print out the values I get:

```
test.at<Vec3b>(1,1)[0] = 2
test.at<Vec3b>(1,1)[1] = d
test.at<Vec3b>(1,1)[2] = /310
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?    I'm running OpenCV 2.10 on a Mac.  Language is C++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are printing out are the ASCII characters for the integer values stored.

For example if you look up the ASCII table, say at this url, http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

You will see that decimal 50 is equivalent to the character '2' and decimal 100 is 'd'.

In C++ you will get this result if you set a value into an `int` variable and then cast that `int` to a `char`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it was something simple that I was just overlooking.  I kept staring at it and couldn't figure out what I was missing.  I'll chock it up to a long day at work. :)  Thanks again!